How to Download a Google Drive Folder as a ZIP File Using PyDrive2
I'm working on a Python script that interacts with Google Drive using the pydrive2 library. My goal is to download an entire folder from Google Drive. I have code that recursively downloads each file in the folder one by one, then zips the files locally. But I've noticed that this approach is significantly slower compared to when I manually download the folder from Google Drive, which automatically zips the contents before downloading.
Here's an example of my current approach:
    def download_folder(self, folder_id, destination):
        if not self.drive:
            raise Exception("Google Drive is not authenticated.")

        # Retrieve the folder metadata to get the folder name
        folder = self.drive.CreateFile({'id': folder_id})
        folder.FetchMetadata(fields='title')
        folder_name = folder['title']

        # Create a directory in the destination with the folder's name
        folder_destination = os.path.join(destination, folder_name)
        os.makedirs(folder_destination, exist_ok=True)

        # List all files in the specified folder
        file_list = self.drive.ListFile({'q': f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()

        for file in file_list:
            print(f'Downloading {file["title"]}...')
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_destination, file['title'])

            # Check if the item is a folder
            if file['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                # Recursively download subfolders
                subfolder_id = file['id']
                self.download_folder(subfolder_id, folder_destination)
            else:
                # Download the file
                file.GetContentFile(file_path)


Is there a way to directly download a Google Drive folder as a ZIP file using pydrive2 or any other method within Python? The goal is to mimic the behavior of manually downloading a folder from Google Drive, where it zips the contents automatically before downloading.
Any help or suggestions for optimizing this process would be greatly appreciated!
